# Context menu on Intellj IDEA

Tags: context-menu, ide, intellij-idea

I have installed Intellij IDEA 10 on Linux (Ubuntu 8.04) and the way the context menu works is annoying me.

The context menu is visible as long as I keep the right button pressed (if I release the button, the menu disappears). To click on a menu item, I have to position the cursor upon the item with the right button pressed and then release it. I've also figured out two alternative ways to keep the menu visible with the right button released:

- To right-click, drag, and release the button outside the context menu.
- Ctrl + Right-click or Shift + Right-click

But I would expect the "normal" behavior: that when I right-click and release, the menu keeps visible until the next click (on an item or outside the menu). Is there a way to change this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue seems to be caused by the Eclipse Keymap in IDEA, it doesn't happen if you choose another keymap. Please see http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-66182.

I've also found a workaround for this problem which is very simple:

> Open Settings | Keymap, press Copy button to create an editable copy of the Eclipse keymap, in the copy find "Show Context Menu" action in the Other group, it has multiple shortcuts defined, delete "Button3 Click" from the list of shortcuts, press Apply. Context menu will no longer disappear after right click.